# Binding JPanel's width to JScrollPane's width to prevent auto resize

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have code that looks something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
           JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

What happens is when the component in the panel becomes too wide, a horizontal scroll bar in the `scrollPane` appears and the user has to scroll left or right. The thing is, the component in panel is actually resizable, but because it's a JScrollPane, it maximizes.

Question: Is there any way I can bind the panel's width property to `scrollPane`'s width property? So that the components inside the panel won't exceed the panel's width?

Below shows what it looks like:

[image: Panel width exceeding jscrollpane]

With the horizontal scroll bar policy set to never, the scroll bar disappears but the panel width remains the same, but now a section of the panel is no longer viewable.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163364/jscrollpane-with-fixed-width/36164503#36164503

Answer (score 1):

You can change the scroll bar policy using the `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy` and `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy` methods or from the constructor `JScrollPane(Component, int, int)`

Quoting [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollbars), the policies are:

- VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED
- HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED
- VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS
- HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS
- VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
- HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestion, the result is as shown in my edit. The scrollbar is no longer there but the panel within the jscrollpane still has its width exceeding the jscrollpane, thus a section of the panel is now no longer viewable.